# Android Room: SELECT DISTINCT for getting multiple columns

Tags: android, android-room

I have query that gives all available trip numbers from `Stations` table (see below). Now I need get more columns in this query: `tripNumber` and also `stationStart` (timestamp as Long) from the first station of the each trip. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Database table structure: `Stations` table contains a set of station-objects for a lot of trips, and when I ask for a trip by its number I will get list of stations.

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT tripNumber FROM Stations")
```

Comment: As I understood. You can do something like : 
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ..., columnN
FROM your_table_name;

Comment: Or if you want other columns information but only tripNumber distinct.
SELECT tripNumber, stationStart
FROM Stations
GROUP BY tripNumber;

Comment: @AbhishekTiwari I need to get lowest `stationStart` for each trip

Comment: By "Lowest" you mean like timestamp in sorted ascending order right? Something like ORDER BY ASC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to want to get the lowest (`min`) `stationstart` per GROUP of trips (`tripnumber`).

Perhaps consider the following that uses the GROUP BY to group each trip as a single output row, along with the earliest stationstart obtained via the `min` [aggregate function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html).

Additionally it demonstrates the `group_concat` [aggregate function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) to output all of the stations of the trip.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stations;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stations (stationName TEXT, tripnumber INTEGER, stationstart TEXT);
INSERT INTO stations VALUES
    ('S1',1,'2024-01-01 10:30')
    ,('S1',3,'2024-01-01 11:30')
    ,('S1',5,'2024-01-01 12:30')
    ,('S2',2,'2024-01-01 10:45')
    ,('S2',3,'2024-01-01 11:45')
    ,('S2',5,'2024-01-01 12:45')
    ,('S3',1,'2024-01-01 11:40')
    ,('S4',1,'2024-01-01 12:15')
    ,('S5',2,'2024-01-01 10:59')
    ,('S7',2,'2024-01-01 11:31')
;
SELECT tripnumber, min(stationstart) AS tripstart,group_concat(stationname) AS allstations FROM stations GROUP BY tripnumber;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS stations;
```

This results in:-

[image]

- i.e. 1 row per trip
- with the earliest stationstart per trip
- and a CSV of all the stations in the trip
- **IF** the above were used ASIS then you would need a suitable POJO for the output objects with fields tripNumber, tripStart and allStations.

***The `DISTINCT` (convoluted) way***

If you really wanted to use DISTINCT, as in `SELECT DISTINCT ....` then you would need to understand that for the 1 row per trip, then ALL rows for that trip have to contain the same data. As such as the other mentioned columns have different data, then that other data would have to not be extracted or extracted later.

CTE (Common Table Expressions) can afford such a result for example *(using the example tables and data from above)* the following:-

```
WITH 
    distinct_trips */<<<<< name given to the CTE table*/ AS 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT tripnumber 
        FROM stations
    )
/* Final use of the CTE */
SELECT 
    tripnumber, 
    (
        SELECT min(stationstart) 
        FROM stations 
        WHERE stations.tripnumber = dt.tripnumber
    ) AS stationstart
FROM distinct_trips AS dt 
;
```

This would output:-

[image]

i.e. as far as the tripnamber and stationstart columns, the same data (but quite clearly in a more convoluted way).

Comment: Thank you for such extended answer, accepted! The first approach looks like most suitable.